# PHP Change Time Zone

Tags: javascript, php, html, directory, ini

How do you change the time zone without php.ini? Is this possible to change the timezone per directory? Preferably without the need to have super user privileges, so I don't have to contact my web provider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Chicago');
```

would set the timezone to 'America/Chicago' for a given script.

Comment: Where would I put that at? At the script at which I want to change the tomezone?

Comment: Thank you i'll accept your answer once I know where to put it.

Comment: you can put it inside each script you would like to set the timezone for. Inside the <?php tags.

Comment: Thank you @Brice

Comment: I have to wait 6 minutes before accepting but afteewhich I will accept